# String lexicographic range query in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, range, elasticsearch

Is it possible to query Elasticsearch giving it a range of strings?

Something that I'd imagine like:

**Sample Mapping:**

```
     {
      "resource" : {
        "properties" : {
          "Title" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "type_" : {
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "type" : "string"
          },
           "Summary" : {
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime",
            "type" : "date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Sample Query:**

```
{
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : [ {
            "text" : {
              "Title" : {
                "query" : "AAA",
                "type" : "phrase_prefix"
              }
            }
          }, {
            "range" : {
              "Title" : {
                "from" : "BBB",
                "to" : "CCC",
                "include_lower" : true,
                "include_upper" : true
              }
            }
          } ],
          "minimum_number_should_match" : 1
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "and" : {
          "filters" : [{
            "or" : {
              "filters" : [ {
                "term" : {
                  "type_" : "personType"
                }
              } ]
            }
          } ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Data Indexed:** 
Resources with `Titles` 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD'

**Result**
Resource with `Title` 'AAA' (range didn't select 'BBB' and 'CCC')

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default ElasticSearch keeps all indexed data lowercase. **It does not lowercase the queries**, though. Great.

To wrap up: after sending the queries (`from` and `to` values) all in lowercase the range searching works like a charm.

Comment: I tried to tell you it was about lowercasing ;) Some queries are actually analyzed, which means that the query goes into the same analysis process as the document field. The Range Query is not one of them. You are relying on the default mapping (which uses the lucene StandardAnalyzer underneath) for the title field, but the query is used as it is, so lowercasing it manually is a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. The [RangeQuery](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/range-query.html) provided by the elasticsearch query DSL internally uses the lucene `TermRangeQuery` for field of type `string`. On the other hand, it uses the lucene `NumericRangeQuery` for field of type number/date.

Comment: Well theres something wrong with my ES, because if I index some resorurces with "name" being dates, then a range query works. If, on the other hand, the "name" are just strings, then the range does not work, always 0 results. How come?

Comment: It probably depends on the way you are indexing data. Have you tried lowercasing the terms in your query?

Comment: well, I have a very basic index mapping because the resources I am indexing have very varied information/fields inside e.g. some have 'name', other have 'title' etc. So I leave it to ES to figure things out and it worked perfectly. But I cant make a range search with strings, even when I have indexed only the names "a","b", "c" and I query with a rage <"a","c"> - no results

Comment: Weird, I just tried what you described and it worked. I'd suggest to check again your data, maybe using the analyze API to see what you're actually indexing.